# Decoding a string in C#

Tags: c#, decode, urldecode

I have a string like `"Akzo_Nobel_N@46@V@46@"`.

The original string is `"Akzo Nobel N.V."`

I need to decode it. I have tried like this

```
public static string Decode(string query)
{
    string dSData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query.ToString());
    return dSData;
}
```

I am not able to decode this into the original string. Please help me decode it.

Comment: And how you get this encoded string?

Comment: You need to find out the exact type of encoding - where does the string come from, who encodes it?

Comment: You need a certain pattern to decode. Is it always this case or are there other cases aswell?

Comment: `@46@` is not URL encoded data, so why would you expect `UrlDecode` to work...

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I get this string from a url, I just splitted the url(using segements)

Comment: This is not a standart URL-encoding, thus the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`-method won't work. Is there any more detailed information about the encoding?

Comment: FYI - %20 is part of a URL for a `space`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String Decode(String query) {
    return query.Replace("_", " ").Replace("@46@", ".");
}
```

More input would provide a better decoding routine.

Comment: This is based on the assumption that these are the only two replacements OP will have to deal with. +1 though, I'm guessing you knew that, and your code is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're ever going to deal with is the 'encoded' version of spaces and full stop characters, then just call a string.replace and replace '_' with ' ' and "@46@" with " ". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx. If it's possible you'll come accross other ascii 'encoding' then you'll need to decode in the right way using the right methods (probably from the same class/library that encoded it).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the format is:

@xx@ where xx is a decimal number for the ASCII character (so a . is 46) and spaces are replaced by underscores.

Looks like a home-brew URL encoding mechanism but could be wrong.

So what you want is a regular expression that looks for something like `@[0-9]{1,3}@` and replace it with the actual character represented by the ascii code.

There may be other straight substitutions other than the _ for spaces, but that's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: How is that in any way relevant?

Comment: The string.replace answer will only sort out the _ and @46@, a regular expression is needed to sort out all potential values based on what I have determined the encoding to be. What if they decode another string that has @64@ in it? (which should be an @ character) You'd need a regular expression to find all the combinations. A string.replace on its own is no use for finding complex patterns, but of course you'd not use a regexp.replace for static strings.